# Receiving the org.hibernate.TypeMismatchException Exception

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I'm working on an application with Spring using SpringMVC, i'm encountering the following error and i don't know how to deal with it .

now i have this message in Console :

```
org.hibernate.TypeMismatchException: Provided id of the wrong type. Expected: class java.lang.Integer, got class java.lang.String
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:86)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:878)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.load(SessionImpl.java:795)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.load(SessionImpl.java:788)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.hibernate.context.ThreadLocalSessionContext$TransactionProtectionWrapper.invoke(ThreadLocalSessionContext.java:301)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy11.load(Unknown Source)
at com.my.dao.DepartementImplDB.getDepartementByNom(DepartementImplDB.java:54)
at com.my.dao.DepartementImplDB.addDepartement(DepartementImplDB.java:29)
at com.my.service.DepartementImplMetier.create(DepartementImplMetier.java:57)
at com.my.controller.ImportController.Read(ImportController.java:279)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.doInvokeMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:710)
at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:167)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:414)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:402)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:771)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:716)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:647)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:563)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:617)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1521)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1478)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

this is my ImportController class

```
/**
 * @author Ilias
 */
package com.my.controller;

//import ...

import com.my.dao.Departement;

@Controller
public class ImportController {


DepartementImplMetier dbD = new DepartementImplMetier();


@RequestMapping(value="/read")
public String Read(Model model,@RequestParam CommonsMultipartFile[] fileUpload) 
        throws IOException, EncryptedDocumentException, InvalidFormatException, java.text.ParseException
{


    liste = extraire(modelnom);

for(int m=0, i=29;i<liste.size();i=i+29){//i=i+29

     Employe employe= new Employe();
     Departement departement = new Departement();

    if(i % 29 == 0) m++;

    //...  Some code here

        String dep = (String)liste.get(29*m+13).toString();

        Departement d = new Departement();
        departement.setNomDepartement(dep);


        boolean bool=true;
        List<Departement> departements = dbD.getAll();


        boolean depbool = true;
        for(int j=0;j< departements.size();j++){
            if(departements.get(j).getNomDepartement() ==  dep )
            {
                depbool = false;
            }

            if(depbool){
            try {
                dbD.create(departement);
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        }

        for(int n=0;n<employes.size();n++){
            if(employes.get(n).getMatriculeMY() ==  (int)mat )
            {
                bool= false;
            }
        }
        if(bool){

        try {
            dbD.create(departement);
            dbE.create(employe);

        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        }

    }
}
return "redirect";
}}
}
```

this is my Employe.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated 5 ao?t 2015 11:05:44 by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.CR1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.my.dao.Employe" table="EMPLOYE">
        <id name="id" type="int">
            <column name="ID" />
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>
        <property name="nomEmploye" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="NOMEMPLOYE" />
        </property>
        <property name="prenomEmploye" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="PRENOMEMPLOYE" />
        </property>
        <property name="matriculeMY" type="int">
            <column name="MATRICULEMY" />
        </property>
        <property name="adresse" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="ADRESSE" />
        </property>
        <property name="sexe" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="SEXE" />
        </property>
        <property name="cin" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="CIN" />
        </property>
        <property name="dateNaissance" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="DATENAISSANCE" />
        </property>
        <property name="situationFamiliale" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="SITUATIONFAMILIALE" />
        </property>
        <property name="dateEntree" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="DATEENTREE" />
        </property>
        <property name="dateSortie" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="DATESORTIE" />
        </property>
        <property name="numCIMR" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="NUMCIMR" />
        </property>
        <property name="numCNSS" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="NUMCNSS" />
        </property>
        <property name="numMUT" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="NUMMUT" />
        </property>
        <property name="profile" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="PROFILE" />
        </property>
        <property name="resteConge" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="RESTECONGE" />
        </property>
        <property name="banque" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="BANQUE" />
        </property>
        <property name="numCpteBanc" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="NUMCPTEBANC" />
        </property>
        <!-- <property name="fonction" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="FONCTION" />
        </property> -->
        <property name="salaire" type="float">
            <column name="SALAIRE" />
        </property>
        <property name="indTransport" type="float">
            <column name="INDTRANSPORT" />
        </property>
        <property name="indRepresent" type="float">
            <column name="INDREPRESENT" />
        </property>
        <property name="indPanier" type="float">
            <column name="INDPANIER" />
        </property>
        <many-to-one name="eDepartement" class="com.my.dao.Departement" access="field" fetch="join">
            <column name="EDEPARTEMENT" />
        </many-to-one>
        <many-to-one name="eFonction" class="com.my.dao.Fonction" access="field" fetch="join">
            <column name="EFONCTION" />
        </many-to-one>
        <many-to-one name="eService" class="com.my.dao.Service" access="field" fetch="join">
            <column name="ESERVICE" />
        </many-to-one>
        <many-to-one name="eTypePaiement" class="com.my.dao.TypePaiement" access="field" fetch="join">
            <column name="ETYPEPAIEMENT" />
        </many-to-one>
        <many-to-one name="eModePaiement" class="com.my.dao.ModePaiement" access="field" fetch="join">
            <column name="EMODEPAIEMENT" />
        </many-to-one>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

this is my Departement.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated 5 ao?t 2015 11:05:44 by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.CR1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.my.dao.Departement" table="DEPARTEMENT">
        <id name="id" type="int">
            <column name="ID" />
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>
        <property name="nomDepartement" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="NOMDEPARTEMENT" />
        </property>
        <set name="Employe" inverse="true">
            <key column="ID" not-null="true"/>
            <one-to-many class="com.my.dao.Employe" />
        </set>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

after debuging, the problem is here :

```
boolean depbool = true;
        for(int j=0;j< departements.size();j++){
            if(departements.get(j).getNomDepartement() ==  dep )
            {
                depbool = false;
            }

            if(depbool){
            try {
                dbD.create(departement);
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        }
```

exactely here :

```
dbD.create(departement);
```

this DepartementImplDB class

```
package com.my.dao;

import java.util.List;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import com.my.util.HibernateUtil;

/**
 * @author Ilias
 *
 */
public class DepartementImplDB implements DepartementDao {

    /**
     * @see com.my.dao.DepartementDao#addDepartement(com.my.dao.Departement)
     */
    @Override
    public int addDepartement(Departement D) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Session session =  HibernateUtil.getInstance().getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();System.out.println("********");
        session.save(D);System.out.println("departement implement metier");
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        D=this.getDepartementByNom(D.getNomDepartement());
        return D.getId();
    }

    /**
     * @see com.my.dao.DepartementDao#getDepartementById(int)
     */
    @Override
    public Departement getDepartementById(int id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Session session =  HibernateUtil.getInstance().getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        Departement dept = (Departement) session.load(Departement.class, id);
        return dept;
    }

    /**
     * @see com.my.dao.DepartementDao#getDepartementByNom(java.lang.String)
     */
    @Override
    public Departement getDepartementByNom(String nomDepartement) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Session session =  HibernateUtil.getInstance().getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        Departement dept = (Departement) session.load(Departement.class, nomDepartement);
        return dept;
    }

    /**
     * @see com.my.dao.DepartementDao#deleteDepartement(int)
     */
    @Override
    public void deleteDepartement(int id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Session session =  HibernateUtil.getInstance().getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        Departement dept = (Departement) session.load(Departement.class, id);
        session.delete(dept);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    }

    /**
     * @see com.my.dao.DepartementDao#updateDepartement(com.my.dao.Departement)
     */
    @Override
    public void updateDepartement(Departement D) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    /**
     * @see com.my.dao.DepartementDao#getAllDepartement()
     */
    @Override
    public List<Departement> getAllDepartement() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Session session =  HibernateUtil.getInstance().getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        return session.createQuery("from Departement").list();          
    }
}
```

this is the link of my last error for more infos : [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31849798/nested-exception-is-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-could-not-initialize-class-c)
**can some one help ?**

Comment: Can you put the code where this is happening?

Comment: Please add the relevant code also to this question. Your other question was about a different problem.

Comment: @Tavo the code is in the other question ?

Comment: @Seb the code is in the other question ?

Comment: The other question is another question. You can't expect people to go around different pages to find a solution for you just because you can't be bothered to put the code here again.

Comment: @Tavo i'm adding the code here, i want to know from you what is the relevant code that help (excuse me I'm beginner in Spring and English is my 3rd language)

Comment: @Tavo i updated the question (the code)

Comment: @Seb i updated the question (the code)

Comment: For the love of god, why do you have so much business logic in Controller, why are you using new ClassName() when you already have spring. Also, the weird way in which you are using loops with 29,30 and such specific numbers is inflexible, and bad practice. I am sure there is a better solution. Also, the code is so much which is of no use, because you should put the relevant, not just do a dump, next you will do a core-dump and ask users on SO to analyze. Doesn't work that way my friend. For starters even if this issue is solved, I would recommend Spring documentation.

Comment: @WeareBorg the loops is for reading Excel file that contain 30 cell (I'm Beginner in spring)

Comment: @WeareBorg thanks for your advice, i'm working just but practicing some tutorials i will read the spring documentation

Comment: I am sure there must be a way to get size of Excel file. I am not much of an Excel expert, but such situations are already taken into consideration. Secondly, create some Service layer classes and move your core logic there. Only post 5-10 relevant lines of effected code for a small problem like different type of variable received. It's so obvious from the error log what the problem is. Also, this is not a Spring problem, this is a Core Java problem. Last but not least, don't use new ClassName(), use Spring to get it, so its lifecycle is managed by Spring.

Comment: what i didn't understand is why -4 for my question ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is

```
org.hibernate.TypeMismatchException: Provided id of the wrong type. Expected: class java.lang.Integer, got class java.lang.String
```

In your stacktrace we can see that dbd.create call others methods

```
    at com.my.dao.DepartementImplDB.getDepartementByNom(DepartementImplDB.java:54)
at com.my.dao.DepartementImplDB.addDepartement(DepartementImplDB.java:29)
```

In your method

```
public Departement getDepartementByNom(String nomDepartement)
```

You try to load a departement with a name but you use session.load wich load by Id.

```
 Departement dept = (Departement) session.load(Departement.class, nomDepartement);
```

You have to make a Criteria request to load by name. Like

```
session.beginTransaction();
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Departement.class);
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("nomDepartement", nomDepartement).ignoreCase());

 result = (Departement) criteria.uniqueResult();
 session.getTransaction().commit();
```

ps: In getDepartementById and getDepartementByNom you never end your transaction. Please use pattern like:

```
 try {
        session.beginTransaction();

        // your code

        session.getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        LOGGER.error(e);
        if (session.getTransaction().isActive()) {
            session.getTransaction().rollback();
        }
    }
```

Comment: i added DepartementImplDB

Comment: now i have an other message,i update my question

Comment: It looks like you have more than one departement with the same name: "org.hibernate.NonUniqueResultException: query did not return a unique result: 20". You can use criteria.list() to have all the departement and getting the first...or juste check why you have multiple departement with the same name if it should be unique

Comment: and when i debug the code it gives me an infenite loop  in :

Comment: I also think you have to check before adding your departement if there is not alreay a departement with the same name.

Comment: `boolean depbool = true;
  for(int j=0;j< departements.size();j++){
   if(departements.get(j).getNomDepartement() ==  dep )
   {
    depbool = false;
   }

   if(depbool){
   try {
    dbD.create(departement);
   } catch (Throwable e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
  }
  }`

Comment: For your infenite loop I think you have to work on a better (more lisible) algorithm because your algorithm really seems strange (duplicate dbD.create(departement), no comments, etc). But this is another question. Try to don't change your question on a same post please

Comment: Ok i will rewrite my code after resolving this problems

Comment: this is the link of the other problem [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31874957/org-hibernate-nonuniqueresultexception-query-did-not-return-a-unique-result-46) PLZ help, and thanks lot for your time

Answer (score 1):

Exception:-
**Provided id of the wrong type. Expected: class java.lang.Integer, got class java.lang.String**

Its very clear by seeing the above line, hibernate is expecting the id as an integer but receiving id in the String format. So it's throwing :-
org.hibernate.TypeMismatchException

Comment: yes i understand it but i didn't found where is the problem

Comment: Paste your entity class of hibernate and which operation you are performing while receiving this exception ?

Comment: Check the id type in Departement.hbm.xml, Employe.hbm.xml, Department.java and Employee.java

Comment: i updated the question (the code)