# org.hibernate.NonUniqueResultException: query did not return a unique result: 462

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I'm working on an application with Spring using SpringMVC,, i'm encountering the following error and i don't know how to deal with it .

now i have this message in Console :

```
org.hibernate.TypeMismatchException: Provided id of the wrong type. Expected: class java.lang.Integer, got class java.lang.String
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:86)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:878)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.load(SessionImpl.java:795)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.load(SessionImpl.java:788)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.hibernate.context.ThreadLocalSessionContext$TransactionProtectionWrapper.invoke(ThreadLocalSessionContext.java:301)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy11.load(Unknown Source)
at com.my.dao.DepartementImplDB.getDepartementByNom(DepartementImplDB.java:54)
at com.my.dao.DepartementImplDB.addDepartement(DepartementImplDB.java:29)
at com.my.service.DepartementImplMetier.create(DepartementImplMetier.java:57)
at com.my.controller.ImportController.Read(ImportController.java:279)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.doInvokeMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:710)
at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:167)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:414)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:402)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:771)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:716)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:647)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:563)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:617)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1521)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1478)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

this is my ImportController class

```
/**
 * @author Ilias
 */
package com.my.controller;

//import ...

import com.my.dao.Departement;

@Controller
public class ImportController {


DepartementImplMetier dbD = new DepartementImplMetier();


@RequestMapping(value="/read")
public String Read(Model model,@RequestParam CommonsMultipartFile[] fileUpload) 
        throws IOException, EncryptedDocumentException, InvalidFormatException, java.text.ParseException
{


    liste = extraire(modelnom);

for(int m=0, i=29;i<liste.size();i=i+29){//i=i+29

     Employe employe= new Employe();
     Departement departement = new Departement();

    if(i % 29 == 0) m++;

    //...  Some code here

        String dep = (String)liste.get(29*m+13).toString();

        Departement d = new Departement();
        departement.setNomDepartement(dep);


        boolean bool=true;
        List<Departement> departements = dbD.getAll();


        boolean depbool = true;
        for(int j=0;j< departements.size();j++){
            if(departements.get(j).getNomDepartement() ==  dep )
            {
                depbool = false;
            }

            if(depbool){
            try {
                dbD.create(departement);
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        }

        for(int n=0;n<employes.size();n++){
            if(employes.get(n).getMatriculeMY() ==  (int)mat )
            {
                bool= false;
            }
        }
        if(bool){

        try {
            dbD.create(departement);
            dbE.create(employe);

        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        }

    }
}
return "redirect";
}}
}
```

this is my Employe.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated 5 ao?t 2015 11:05:44 by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.CR1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.my.dao.Employe" table="EMPLOYE">
        <id name="id" type="int">
            <column name="ID" />
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>
        <property name="nomEmploye" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="NOMEMPLOYE" />
        </property>
        <property name="prenomEmploye" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="PRENOMEMPLOYE" />
        </property>
        <property name="matriculeMY" type="int">
            <column name="MATRICULEMY" />
        </property>
        <property name="adresse" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="ADRESSE" />
        </property>
        <property name="sexe" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="SEXE" />
        </property>
        <property name="cin" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="CIN" />
        </property>
        <property name="dateNaissance" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="DATENAISSANCE" />
        </property>
        <property name="situationFamiliale" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="SITUATIONFAMILIALE" />
        </property>
        <property name="dateEntree" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="DATEENTREE" />
        </property>
        <property name="dateSortie" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="DATESORTIE" />
        </property>
        <property name="numCIMR" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="NUMCIMR" />
        </property>
        <property name="numCNSS" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="NUMCNSS" />
        </property>
        <property name="numMUT" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="NUMMUT" />
        </property>
        <property name="profile" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="PROFILE" />
        </property>
        <property name="resteConge" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="RESTECONGE" />
        </property>
        <property name="banque" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="BANQUE" />
        </property>
        <property name="numCpteBanc" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="NUMCPTEBANC" />
        </property>
        <!-- <property name="fonction" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="FONCTION" />
        </property> -->
        <property name="salaire" type="float">
            <column name="SALAIRE" />
        </property>
        <property name="indTransport" type="float">
            <column name="INDTRANSPORT" />
        </property>
        <property name="indRepresent" type="float">
            <column name="INDREPRESENT" />
        </property>
        <property name="indPanier" type="float">
            <column name="INDPANIER" />
        </property>
        <many-to-one name="eDepartement" class="com.my.dao.Departement" access="field" fetch="join">
            <column name="EDEPARTEMENT" />
        </many-to-one>
        <many-to-one name="eFonction" class="com.my.dao.Fonction" access="field" fetch="join">
            <column name="EFONCTION" />
        </many-to-one>
        <many-to-one name="eService" class="com.my.dao.Service" access="field" fetch="join">
            <column name="ESERVICE" />
        </many-to-one>
        <many-to-one name="eTypePaiement" class="com.my.dao.TypePaiement" access="field" fetch="join">
            <column name="ETYPEPAIEMENT" />
        </many-to-one>
        <many-to-one name="eModePaiement" class="com.my.dao.ModePaiement" access="field" fetch="join">
            <column name="EMODEPAIEMENT" />
        </many-to-one>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

this is my Departement.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated 5 ao?t 2015 11:05:44 by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.CR1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.my.dao.Departement" table="DEPARTEMENT">
        <id name="id" type="int">
            <column name="ID" />
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>
        <property name="nomDepartement" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="NOMDEPARTEMENT" />
        </property>
        <set name="Employe" inverse="true">
            <key column="ID" not-null="true"/>
            <one-to-many class="com.my.dao.Employe" />
        </set>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

after debuging, the problem is here :

```
boolean depbool = true;
        for(int j=0;j< departements.size();j++){
            if(departements.get(j).getNomDepartement() ==  dep )
            {
                depbool = false;
            }

            if(depbool){
            try {
                dbD.create(departement);
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        }
```

exactely here :

```
dbD.create(departement);
```

this DepartementImplDB class

```
package com.my.dao;

import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Criteria;
import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.criterion.Restrictions;

import com.my.util.HibernateUtil;

/**
 * @author Ilias
 *
 */
public class DepartementImplDB implements DepartementDao {


    /**
     * @see com.my.dao.DepartementDao#addDepartement(com.my.dao.Departement)
     */
    @Override
    public int addDepartement(Departement D) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Session session =  HibernateUtil.getInstance().getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();System.out.println("********");
        session.save(D);System.out.println("departement implement metier");
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        D=this.getDepartementByNom(D.getNomDepartement());
        return D.getId();
    }

    /**
     * @see com.my.dao.DepartementDao#getDepartementById(int)
     */
    @Override
    public Departement getDepartementById(int id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Session session =  HibernateUtil.getInstance().getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        Departement dept = new Departement();
        try {
            session.beginTransaction();
            dept = (Departement) session.load(Departement.class, id);
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            //LOGGER.error(e);
            e.printStackTrace();
            if (session.getTransaction().isActive()) {
                session.getTransaction().rollback();
            }
        }
        return dept;
    }

    /**
     * @see com.my.dao.DepartementDao#getDepartementByNom(java.lang.String)
     */
    @Override
    public Departement getDepartementByNom(String nomDepartement) {

         Session session =  HibernateUtil.getInstance().getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
         Departement result = new Departement();

         try {
                session.beginTransaction();
                Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Departement.class);
                criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("nomDepartement", nomDepartement).ignoreCase());

                result = (Departement) criteria.uniqueResult();
                session.getTransaction().commit();


            } catch (HibernateException e) {
                //LOGGER.error(e);
                e.printStackTrace();
                if (session.getTransaction().isActive()) {
                    session.getTransaction().rollback();
                }
            }
            return result;

    }

    /**
     * @see com.my.dao.DepartementDao#deleteDepartement(int)
     */
    @Override
    public void deleteDepartement(int id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Session session =  HibernateUtil.getInstance().getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        Departement dept = (Departement) session.load(Departement.class, id);
        session.delete(dept);
        session.getTransaction().commit();

    }

    /**
     * @see com.my.dao.DepartementDao#updateDepartement(com.my.dao.Departement)
     */
    @Override
    public void updateDepartement(Departement D) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    /**
     * @see com.my.dao.DepartementDao#getAllDepartement()
     */
    @Override
    public List<Departement> getAllDepartement() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Session session =  HibernateUtil.getInstance().getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        return session.createQuery("from Departement").list();          
    }
}
```

this is what i want to do (UML): [imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJSud.png)
this is the link of my last error for more infos : [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31872161/receiving-the-org-hibernate-typemismatchexception-exception)
**can some one help ?**

Answer (score 3):

Your question is a real mess... but if you read the exception:

> Provided id of the wrong type. **Expected**: class java.lang.**Integer**, **got class** java.lang.**String**

Anf after you take a look to your `Departement` class, it has only 2 fields and one set (according to the hibernate mapping):

```
int id;
String nomDepartament;
Set employees;
```

That only can mean, youre passing the `nomDepartament` field instead of `id` somewhere in your code...

But as far as you are not providing, the `Departement` class or `DepartementImplMetier.create()` method, that is the one causing the exception I cannot say more...

So... [start here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) focus your problems, and provide only important parts of the code.

Comment: when i write `Set<Employe> ` instead of `private Set<Employe> Employe;` i have the previous problem [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31872161/receiving-the-org-hibernate-typemismatchexception-exception)